# Downgrade cups / SAMSUNG printer error

Tags: printing, downgrade

With a recent cups update my ML-1640 printer has stopped working.

A [fresh post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265299) from ARCHLINUX offers a fix by downgrading to 2.3.3op1-1 from my current cups:amd64/hirsute 2.3.3op2-3ubuntu3.

How can I downgrade?

```
sudo apt-cache madison cups
```

only shows one version. Is this the right place to look:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/amd64/cups ?

### Building from source

Do I need to build from source? If yes which? Can I use the ARCH archive https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/c/cups/? Or is it best to build from GIT https://github.com/apple/cups/releases ?

Comment: 21.04 (hirsute) packages are off-topic here for another week. While in pre-release testing, you should be bisecting to find the commit that created the reversion, filing a bug report to report the reversion, and testing the dailies to ensure the bug gets fixed. If you did not intend to be a tester, then 21.04 was perhaps a poor choice...until next week, when it becomes a great choice.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Apologies, will do.